# Why doesn't this reference to document.querySelectorAll work?

Tags: javascript

For funsies, I tried to create a shorthand version of document.querySelectorAll by making it usable like the way jQuery does it. Here is the code:

```
window.$ = document.querySelectorAll;

var links;
links = document.querySelectorAll('a'); // Works
links = $('a'); // Doesn't work
```

For some reason, `$` isn't working even though it is a reference to `document.querySelectorAll`. I know that I could do this instead:

```
function $(selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

but I just don't understand why the first example doesn't work.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: *querySelectorAll* is an interface that expects to be called on some object that supports the interface, so it needs to have its *this* set to that object. You probably need a function anyway since you might want to provide a different root element, e.g. `function $(selector, root) { root = root || document; return root.querySelectorAll(selector);}`..

Answer (score 1):

Different `this` variables:

```
document.querySelectorAll() -> `this` is document
querySelectorAll() -> `this` is window
```

Comment: `window.$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);` solves the problem.

Comment: In ES6 you can use `((w,d)=>{w.$=d.querySelectorAll.bind(d)})(window,document);`